# unknown parameters in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm looking at the Yahoo Finance API, which can be found [here](https://github.com/jollyca/startup-engineering-homework/blob/master/homework-2/market-research.js~) and [here](http://pastebin.com/EgFatyd3) as well.

I'm new to node.js, so this is a pretty simple question.

In the `var buildfn = function(csvfile, headers)` function, another function is called,  `var response2console = function(result, response)`.

I've read up on closer, what I don't understand is where the parameters (result, response) in the second function, response2console, come from. They are not global variables, and they aren't defined locally in the function either, so how are they defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They'll come from when the function is *called*.

e.g.

```
var marketResearch = function(symbols, columns, csvfile, headers) {
    symbols = symbols || SYMBOLS_DEFAULT;
    columns = columns || COLUMNS_DEFAULT;
    csvfile = csvfile || CSVFILE_DEFAULT;
    headers = headers || HEADERS_DEFAULT;
    var apiurl = financeurl(symbols, columns);
    var response2console = buildfn(csvfile, headers);
    rest.get(apiurl).on('complete', response2console);
};
```

Comment: but the response2console var in the marketResearch is not the same as the response2console in the buildfn, correct? I mean I know they are set equal to each other, but they aren't the same in that when response2console is called in the bulidfn function, it does not define response2console in the marketResearch function

Comment: `response2console` here is the return value of `buildfn(csvfile, headers);`, so it *is* the same as the `response2console` defined there since that is the return value of `buildfn`.

Comment: alos, I still dont understand the values given to the parameters (result, response) are those parameters just set equal to (csvfile, headers) when response2console is called?

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks, that's what I wasn't sure about.

Comment: so anytime functions are embedded in each other like that, they just adopt the parameters of the function they are embedded in?